# выдает ошибку: not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
df = pd.read_csv('new-site.csv')
 
regex = "\d{1}"

df['site'] = df['site\tdwell-time'].str.findall(regex).str.get(0)

df.sample(2)

df['group'] = df['site'].apply(lambda x: 'B' if x > 0 else 'A')

df.head(5)

df.group.value_counts().unique()
```

Comment: на какой строчке то ругается?

Comment: df['site'] = df['site\tdwell-time'].str.findall(regex).str.get(0)

Comment: Очень странно, я не смог такую ошибку воспроизвести, даже когда подал на вход числа, а не строки. Приведите **полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе**. И желательно сами данные тоже показать.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('new-site.csv') 
regex = '\d{1}' # регулярное выражение для нахождения чисел до разделителя "\"
df
df['site'] = df['site\tdwell-time'].str.findall(regex).str.get(0)
df

Comment: так без ошибки    выдает

Comment: df['group'] = df['site'].apply(lambda x: 'B' if x > 0 else 'A')    уже с ошибкой

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что такая ошибка может быть только здесь:

```
df['group'] = df['site'].apply(lambda x: 'B' if x > 0 else 'A')
                                                ^^^^^
```

У вас в этой колонке цифры, но в виде строк, поэтому сравнение с числом `0` не работает. Можно попробовать исправить преобразованием в `int` перед этой строкой:

```
df['site'] = df['site'].astype(int)
```

Но вообще хорошо бы понять - что у вас в данных и чего вы пытаетесь добиться. Без этого моё решение может сработать, а может и нет.

Comment: df['site'] = df['site'].astype(int)    помогло . спасибо